# How can I reduce lag in Assassin's Creed 4: Black Flag?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I am experiencing significant lag while playing AC4BF.

Movement is very slow and the voices do not synchronize with lip movement.

I have an Intel Core i5-2500 3.3GHz CPU and 3.24 GB RAM, and Radeon HD 6350 graphic card
which is well above the system requirements of this game.

I had already adjusted graphics settings but it does not fix the problem.

How can I play this game with normal speed? Is my system still not adequate?

Comment: The game seems to be unoptimized, especially for AMD graphics cards. Try [updating your drivers](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx). If that doesn't help, you might have to wait for a later driver release.

Comment: < 4 GB of ram is really, not a lot at all. My laptop (non-primary device, work computer) that is 5 years old has a 6350 in it and 8GB of ram. I do not say this to talk down about your computer, but simply to point out that your system specs are quite old and underpowered for a "latest gen" game that has heavy graphics. Even if your system meets minimum specs, does not guarantee that it will run well, you may also have a lot of other things going on with the system eating available resources and/or degrading performance.

Comment: Install 64 bit already. You not only cripple your RAM usage, but also the performance of your CPU and GPU. Stop living in the 90s.

Comment: Are you running the game from an external device by any chance? Also, when you play, try keeping it the only program running at the time. Not much more you can do without better specs.

Answer (score 2):

Try lowering the graphics settings if possible. It's likely you have them set higher than your system is capable of running.

If you have a 64bit OS, the cheapest and immediate performance upgrade you can do would be a simple RAM upgrade. Ram is still relatively cheap these days, and bumping yourself up to 6 or 8GB if possible will yield a nice boost all around, not just in gaming. Modern OS's like Win7 are pretty RAM hungry, and if you are running a game on top of that, it may starve it out causing your OS to Swap/Page RAM onto your hard drive, which is considerably slower in performance. This is likely part of your problem.

Also, a video card upgrade usually is the single most important/cost effective/noticeable  upgrade you can do for gaming. It provides immediate and noticeable results. I recommend checking out Tom's Hardware GPU Hierarchy Chart. They update it usually every month and it gives a general idea where your video card stacks up against what is out today. As they recommend, it's usually not worth upgrading until you jump 2 or more levels on the chart. Then you get the best bang-for-your-buck. I tend to upgrade my video card usually once every other year, sometimes every year (depending on my tax refund, hehe). But, I consider this more frequent than most, so every other year or so you can probably get away with and still playing most games on high/medium-high settings, given there are no other bottlenecks such as RAM or really slow hard drives (5400rpm drives).

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-card-review,3107-7.html

If your specific card is not listed, just round-about-it, such as 6350 round to 6300 series or there-about to guestimate where your out.

Comment: Actually I have 8 GB Ram, but using only 3.24GB because my Win 7 is 32bit version. Upgrading my OS to 64bit version would be helpful then.

Comment: a video card will be your single easiest and least disruptive upgrade to your system. An OS reinstall is usually not too much fun to do, but I do agree, going to the 64bit version will enable you to fully take advantage of the hardware you already own.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Try disconnecting from the internet and see if that fixes your issue.**

Believe it or not the lag you are experiencing probably has nothing to do with your system specifications. In fact, I was having the same problems on my rig, which is beyond recommended requirements. I realized once I disconnected from the internet that regardless of graphics settings, I could run at high FPS (frames per second).   In contrast, while connected to the internet, I only was getting 15 - 20 FPS.